# Apache mod_rewrite - want a file system redirect not a 301 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have example1.com on a shared web host running Apache.  It has a directory example1.com/foo.  I now want example2.com to serve the same content from example1.com/foo, except at the example2.com root without the intervening directory in the URL.  Like example2.com/bar.html should serve the same content as example1.com/foo/bar.html .

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ foo/$1 [NC]
```

This simple rewrite rule takes any request intended for example2.com and inserts the foo/ to point to the content which is in that directory.  Problem is this keeps doing an external 301 redirect.  I don't want that, I want the browser to stay on example2.com without redirecting while Apache serves up the content from /foo in the filesystem.

Been over the Apache mod_rewrite docs several times, which say how to force a 301 redirect with the [R] flag but don't say how to force it NOT to happen.  What am I missing here?  It is behaving the same on both my Linux shared host and a local test with Apache on Windows.

Thanks!

Comment: Is DocumentRoot same for both domains?

Comment: Yes.  I don't have the ability to change it on the shared web host.

Comment: Actually I see now what I'm really trying to do is have DocumentRoot behave differently for the two different domains.  I don't have the ability to change the server config on the shared web host though.  Is it possible to remap DocumentRoot through a mod_rewrite rule in .htaccess based on http_host?  I'm doubting it since Apache needs DocumentRoot already set to find .htaccess in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out.  The 301 was happening because I had the directory name wrong in the rule.  So the result of the rule pointed to a path that didn't exist, which makes Apache try to fallback from the file system redirect to a 301 redirect.

Then I had to fix an infinite loop, since that above rule always adds "foo" to the URL even if it's already present so I'd get foo/foo/foo/foo/... .  We need to add it only if it's not already there.  Had to do it with this two-step rule, because you can't use wildcards in a capturing group of a negative rule.  But this seems to work, adding "foo" when the host is example2.com and the URL does not already contain "foo".

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^foo - [C]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ foo/$1 [NC,PT]
```